# From AWS CDK, how do we get the current IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I want to get the current IAM user deploying the stack. Since we already have aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key, how can I get the iam user?

For development purpose, this will allow us to create custom stacks based on the user running them.

Regards And Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Call STS [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) using the credentials.

It will return something like the following and you can retrieve the IAM user from the Arn:

```
UserId: "AIDASAMPLEUSERID",
Account: "123456789012",
Arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/DevAdmin"
```

Comment: Hi @jarmod I don't see any GetCallerIdentity usage for the CDK.

Comment: It may not be exposed by the CDK. You can import the relevant AWS SDK (e.g. boto3 for Python).